# How at other way transfer the message from one PHP page to other?

Tags: php

I just transfer the message from page1.php to page2.php like this:

page1.php:

```
header('Location: admin.php?message=1');
```

page2.php:

```
if (isset($_GET["message"]))
echo "Login fail, please try again.";
```

How at other way transfer the message from one PHP page to other and what is the best way?

Comment: You just did it. If not as a GET parameter, then as a POST parameter, or as a separate header. Voting to close as too broad.

Comment: if you use header this is the only way.. or use session or cookie.. but carefully

Comment: @MattClark Could you edit my question against being too wide? I'm very satisfied with answers and would be pity delete all that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a good enough approach, the other is using sessions:
The contents of page1.php:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['message'] = "Login fail, please try again.";
header('Location: admin.php');
```

The contents of page2.php would be something like:

```
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION["message"]))
{
    echo $_SESSION['message'];
    unset($_SESSION['message']);
}
```